# Newly created jenkins jobs not running on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am creating new jobs for my selenium python scripts. My old jobs are running fine, but my newly created jobs do not run . I tried copying and pasting the configurations from my old jobs to the new one , but still new jobs won't run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution , there was a memory issue with the AWS machine on which jenkins is deployed

Answer (score 0):

can you provide more information? what is the configuration? what do you see in the log?

did you check the labels for the nodes? you might be running on a restricted node or on master or the master doesn't allow jobs to be executed for example ...